# setup softap on tiwi-r2 wl1271 on arm embedded-linux: authentication timeout

Tags: authentication, timeout, arm, embedded-linux

I have an embedded arm linux device running

```
kernel 2.6.39.4 
hostapd 2.0
wl1271 and wl1271_sdio modules loaded (no compat drivers)
```

The device is a [TiWi-R2 module from TI](http://www.lsr.com/wireless-products/tiwi-r2).
Adhoc and Infrastructure mode work but when I try to set up a softap I run into problems:
I created a station with no encryption by setting the contents of my hostapd.conf to:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
channel=1
hw_mode=g
ssid=mya
```

The firmware that is being booted:

```
[ 6486.330000] wl1271: wlan power up
[ 6486.660000] booting firmware ti-connectivity/wl1271-fw-ap.bin
[ 6486.810000] wl1271: firmware booted (Rev 6.2.1.0.54)
```

The SSID is being broadcast and other devices can see it but can't associate. On an Ubuntu laptop, after a failed attempt to connect, I get the following from dmesg:

```
[  548.289020] wlan0: authenticate with 00:xx:yy:zz:ww:qq
[  548.300588] wlan0: send auth to 00:xx:yy:zz:ww:qq (try 1/3)
[  548.504059] wlan0: send auth to 00:xx:yy:zz:ww:qq (try 2/3)
[  548.708059] wlan0: send auth to 00:xx:yy:zz:ww:qq (try 3/3)
[  548.912056] wlan0: authentication with 00:xx:yy:zz:ww:qq timed out
```

After failing to associate, the laptop connects to another previously configured access point. Starting hostapd with the -dd option on the embedded device, I can get some debug messages but I don't understand them very well. This is the output of the hostapd side while the laptop is connecting:

```
wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (20) received
mgmt::auth
authentication: STA=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff auth_alg=0 auth_transaction=1 status_code=0 wep=0
  New STA
ap_sta_add: register ap_handle_timer timeout for aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff (300 seconds - ap_max_inactivity)
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff IEEE 802.11: authentication OK (open system)
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff MLME: MLME-AUTHENTICATE.indication(aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, OPEN_SYSTEM)
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff MLME: MLME-DELETEKEYS.request(aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff)
authentication reply: STA=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff auth_alg=0 auth_transaction=2 resp=0 (IE len=0)
wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (20) received
mgmt::auth
authentication: STA=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff auth_alg=0 auth_transaction=1 status_code=0 wep=0
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff IEEE 802.11: authentication OK (open system)
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff MLME: MLME-AUTHENTICATE.indication(aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, OPEN_SYSTEM)
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff MLME: MLME-DELETEKEYS.request(aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff)
authentication reply: STA=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff auth_alg=0 auth_transaction=2 resp=0 (IE len=0)
wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (20) received
mgmt::auth
authentication: STA=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff auth_alg=0 auth_transaction=1 status_code=0 wep=0
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff IEEE 802.11: authentication OK (open system)
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff MLME: MLME-AUTHENTICATE.indication(aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, OPEN_SYSTEM)
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff MLME: MLME-DELETEKEYS.request(aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff)
authentication reply: STA=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff auth_alg=0 auth_transaction=2 resp=0 (IE len=0)
```

and after some time, it seems the system is disassociating the laptop because of inactivity:

```
ap_handle_timer: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff flags=0x1 timeout_next=0
wlan0: Timeout, sending disassociation info to STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
ap_handle_timer: register ap_handle_timer timeout for aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff (1 seconds - AP_DISASSOC_DELAY)
ap_handle_timer: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff flags=0x1 timeout_next=1
wlan0: Timeout, sending disassociation info to STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff IEEE 802.11: disassociated due to inactivity
ap_handle_timer: register ap_handle_timer timeout for aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff (1 seconds - AP_DEAUTH_DELAY)
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff MLME: MLME-DISASSOCIATE.indication(aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, 4)
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff MLME: MLME-DELETEKEYS.request(aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff)
ap_handle_timer: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff flags=0x1 timeout_next=2
wlan0: Timeout, sending deauthentication info to STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to inactivity (timer DEAUTH/REMOVE)
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff MLME: MLME-DEAUTHENTICATE.indication(aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff, 2)
wlan0: STA aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff MLME: MLME-DELETEKEYS.request(aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff)
ap_free_sta: cancel ap_handle_timer for aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

I saw a similar post in [bugzilla](http://hostap.epitest.fi/bugz/show_bug.cgi?id=248) but the post is old, pertains to wpa_supplicant(version 0.6.0) and the laptop has Ubuntu 13.04 on it with wpa_supplicant 1.0. It made me think that somehow hostapd isn't notifying the client that the association was successful.

I can't connect to the softap from any other device either. I tried Android 4.4 and iOS 7.0.4

I also tried the wpa2 configuration and the standard open [configuration files from TI](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/OMAP_Wireless_Connectivity_NLCP_WLAN_AP_Configuration_Scripts#Access_Point_configuration_-_Non_Secured_network) but nothing worked.

**EDIT**:
I had not idea that I would stump the whole community on this one... I have upgraded to the TiWi-BLE module, the official successor to the TiWi-R2 but haven't managed to get any further.

I have found a post with the same problem but without a solution [here](http://e2e.ti.com/support/low_power_rf/f/307/p/239851/885787.aspx#885787).

**EDIT**:
I have resolved the problem by using kernel 3.12.0 where this problem does not occur. It seems to me like the problem lies in the kernel. I will leave this question unanswered for a while, in case someone who can help sees it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to a newer kernel. At that time it was 3.13.0-next, a kernel without an official release but since it worked perfectly I kept it at that.